# Stuck in an infinite login loop after replacing PATH

Tags: login-screen

I replaced PATH in `sudo gedit /etc/environment` to the usual Linux path `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`. The current `/etc/environment` only has:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

Also ran `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_111`.

After rebooting the system, I am stuck in an infinite login loop.
Help please.

**I am showing the output of `tail ~/.xsession-errors`, `ls /sbin/init`, `type -a init`, `init`, `which init`**

`tail ~/.xsession-errors` returns

```
Script for ibus started at run_im. 
Script for auto started at run_im. 
Script for default started at run_im. 
/etc/x11/Xsession.d/99*11-common _start: line 5: exec: init: not found
```

`ls /sbin/init` returns `/sbin/int`

`type -a init` returns `-bash: type: init: not found`

`init` returns

```
Command 'init' is available in '/sbin/init'
 The command could not be loaded because '/sbin' is not included in the PATH  environment variable. 
 This is most likely caused by the lack of administrative privileges associated with your account. 
 init: command not found
```

`which init` Shell remains quiet and returns the blinking cursor.

**The solutions that I have already tried are:**

1)  I typed **`chown hvs:hvs .Xauthority`** and pressed enter the shell was quiet and returned to the blinking cursor. Went to login screen, still stuck.

2) I entered **`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`**, then I got this menu to select Default display manager: gdm or lightdm. On selecting lightdm, it returns to the blinking cursor. I rebooted and the only difference is that Ubuntu switched to lightdm from GDM. Did't work either.

3) I also tried resetting my **Unity Configuration**.

4) I **Reinstalled Ubuntu desktop**. It didn't work, so I **installed Gnome desktop**. Didn't work either.

5) Edited `~/.profile` in GNU nano to default script:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
   # include .bashrc if it exists
   if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
      . "$HOME/.bashrc"
   fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

6) **made a new user account**. No use.

**Haven't tried** the *GRUB menu and the rescue mode to mount the filesystem in `rw mode` then edit that file*

Anyone got any other solution?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation and all comments that were here have been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51201/discussion-on-question-by-harshvardhansharma-stuck-in-an-infinite-login-loop-aft).

Answer (score -1):

you should edit /etc/environment to following
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_111
no export.
Just use ctrl alt f1 go to log-in command. use /usr/bin/sudo nano /etc/environment and edit it.
then reboot you should be able to login